# Optional or Null Parameters JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am new to Eclipselink JPA. I have a set of complex search queries with a number of search parameters, some of the parameters are optional. Is there a way to specify optional parameters in named query? Is the below approach an efficient way to do?
select o from Product o WHERE :value is null or o.category = :value'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach would probably work, but I normally use the [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) in similar situations. For example, you could conditionally add predicates to your criteria query if the parameters are provided:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> cq = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> e = cq.from(Product.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (categoryValue != null)
  predicates.add(cb.equal(e.get("category"), categoryValue));
if (someOtherValue != null)
  predicates.add(cb.equal(e.get("someField"), someOtherValue));

// AND all of the predicates together:
if (!predicates.isEmpty())
  cq.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

List<Product> products = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This is kind of an ugly example, but the `CriteriaBuilder` is very powerful once you become familiar with the API.

Comment: What about if category in db is null but categoryValue is null? This query will get a result!

Comment: @MikeArgyriou Not sure I fully understand your question, but if `categoryValue` is `null` then that is essentially saying "don't filter my results by category", so the result set could contain products with _any_ category.